# How to describe when someone hesitates before speaking?

Tags: fiction, dialogue, description

I find myself repeatedly saying "he/she hesitated" when I feel like there's something else I could say. I've been experimenting but with the character in question, all I can think of is, "he croaked" which isn't quite right. So, how would you describe someone who hesitates before speaking?

Comment: could be this helpful? https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/showing-a-brief-hesitation

Comment: @Zavael Yes, it was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tip:

> Don't tell the reader that the answer is 4, instead tell them the answer is 2+2

Don't tell the reader that a character is hestitating, instead find a way a round-about way of describing the hesitation.

Key-words would be, for example:

- Fear
- Uncertainty
- Brief pause
- Unwillingness

There's nothing wrong with being forthcoming with it either, it's a matter of trying to find a good balance of **show and tell**.

There's no pattern to follow when it comes to show and tell; it's up to you to figure out the balance for your story.

Comment: This is a good answer. Look for other ways to convey the uncertainty. In addition to the ideas above, you can use an occasional *he/she stammered, "dialog."* Or dig deeper than the hesitation--use immersion to imply the nerves. *This was too like the grilling before the thesis committee, and he/she felt as unprepared now as then. "dialog."*  Or, *Caught off-guard, he/she said, "dialog".* Or simply fill in the space with beats (a few sentences) and then say, *Finally, he/she broke the silence. "Dialog."* Keep at it, and notice tricks in your reading and try them out.

Comment: @SFWriter I find 'stammer' is wildly overused by writers looking to get away from too many 'he said's. In practice there aren't many situations where people, who don't have a speech impediment, utter words falteringly or make *involuntary* stops and repetitions. It isn't a good synonym for voluntary hesitation.